# Sum index wise lists based on index comparison

Tags: python

I have multiple lists, let´s say:

```
t1 = ['ABC', 100, 20]
t2 = ['XXX', 200, 35]
t3 = ['ABC', 500, 90]
t4 = ['XXX', 100, 15]
```

I want to sum the second and third elements from all lists only if the first ones are equal, resulting:

```
list = [['ABC', 600, 110], ['XXX', 300, 50]]
```

Tried with `map() function` but couldn't get it done.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Equal to what? To the first list, ie. `t1[0]` ?

Comment: What if more than one lists is equal, for example you have another `XXX` as well?

Comment: What is the desired output? Will it be a list of lists, or just a bunch of lists? And how are your input lists organized, so that they will be looped in the code (eg are in the same directory, dictionary, etc?

Comment: Consider `lists = itertools.groupby(sorted([t1, t2, t3]), key=lambda list_: list_[0])`. From there, you can use `sum` on the `zip` of the members of each group...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (no need for external library)

```
from collections import defaultdict
t1 = ['ABC', 100, 20]
t2 = ['XXX', 200, 35]
t3 = ['ABC', 500, 90]
t4 = ['XXX', 100, 15]
t_lst = [t1,t2,t3,t4]


d = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
for t in t_lst:
  d[t[0]][0] += t[1]
  d[t[0]][1] += t[2]
final = [[k,v[0],v[1]] for k,v in d.items()]
print(final)
```

output

```
[['ABC', 600, 110], ['XXX', 300, 50]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with an intermediate [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of [`numpy` arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) to create some kind of a costume counter:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

lists = [['ABC', 100, 20], ['XXX', 200, 35], ['ABC', 500, 90], ['XXX', 100, 15]]

res = defaultdict(lambda: np.array([0, 0]))
for l in lists:
    res[l[0]] += l[1:]

print(res)
print([[key] + list(vals) for key, vals in res.items()])
```

Gives:

```
{'ABC': array([600, 110]), 'XXX': array([300,  50])}
[['ABC', 600, 110], ['XXX', 300, 50]]
```